# Check if the given set is path connected

Tags: general-topology

$\{(x,y) | y=x \sin(1/x ), x>0\}\cup \{0,0\}$ . 
I know this set is connected as the closure of a connected set is connect. But I cannot think of any path from  a point to origin.

Comment: The graph contains the origin so the union is pointless, and the path connecting the two is the graph itself. Did you perhaps mean $\sin(1/x)$?

Comment: my bad , tex skills are poor! I have made the changes!

Comment: not a duplicate at all ! This is different from topologist sine curve!